# graficar varias variables en una misma ventana en python usando subplot

Tags: python

tengo un problema, estoy usando python para graficar varias variables seleccionadas por el usuario(contienen como una lista por cada variable) lo que intento hacer es graficar 1 o mas variables dependiendo de cuantas seleccione el usuario, en una misma ventana usando subplot.
porque el codigo que tengo (adjunto mas abajo) si me imprime las graficas pero con diferente ventana, pasa algo raro. porque solo me aparece una. pero cuando cierro esa ventana me abre la otra.

codigo en python

[image: codigo]

Comment: saca el `plt.show()`  fuera del bucle.

Comment: ohh, muchas gracias. me sirvió de mucha ayuda.  si hace lo que pedía